# Input problems scanf()/getchar()

Tags: c, scanf, getchar

I am making a text based game, and i am having a big problem with input. Here is a *small* example of my problem code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char c;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    system("clear");

    while(1){
        printf("\nInput a character.\n");
        c = getchar();
        printf("\nYour input: %c\n", c);
        sleep(1);
        system("clear");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, if you compile/run this, and type in 'abc', it will just take each one, and send it through the loop. What I need it to do is only take the very *first* character that someone types in, no matter how many they do type in.

And, PS: I have tried it this way, and it does the same thing:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char c[2];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    system("clear");

    while(1){
        printf("\nInput a character.\n");
        scanf("%1s", c);
        printf("\nYour input: %c\n", c[0]);
        sleep(1);
        system("clear");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: It also adds a space to what ever you type in, I assume it is a \0, but im not sure. Thanks!

Comment: Typically, stdin is buffered until the user presses the enter key. The method for getting single characters varies based on your OS. Which OS are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: It's actually really frustrating that the standard does not give a nice way of handling this situation. On POSIX systems you can use `getline`, which works very nicely.

Comment: but i only want one character

Comment: Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can add 1 more line to read all the characters that come after the first one until there is a newline character (i.e. the user presses Enter):

```
while (getchar() != '\n');
```

Adding to your example, it would be like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char c;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

system("clear");

while(1){
    printf("\nInput a character.\n");
    c = getchar();
    printf("\nYour input: %c\n", c);
    sleep(1);
    system("clear");
    while (getchar() != '\n');
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use `scanf`, enter a string and hit the `ENTER` key, a string and a character are placed in the input buffer, they are namely: the entered string and the newline character. The string or character by character gets consumed by the scanf but the newline remains in the input buffer, unless you consume that too.

`getchar()`, on the other hand will not wait for ENTER key, it would read character by character, then your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getch()` which does not wait for a newline.

Answer (score 0):

What i think you look for is something like this code, to save very first character, you can also check if `c` `==` `'\n`' to continue your operation, but i dont know what you want after saving very first character:

```
 int i,c;
char save;
for ( i = 0;(c=getchar())!= EOF ; i++)
{
    if ( i == 0)
        save = c;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fgets()`, and extract its first character, like...

```
char ch[2], c;
fgets(ch, 2, stdin);
c = ch[0];
```